# Photoshop - Removing an Object using the Content Aware function

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I needed to remove something from my picture of computer on the table and restore the structure of the table when the object is no longer there.
I have accomplished already removing the object and filling it with a structure using Quick Select tool, then `Edit > Fill > Content Aware`.
My problem is that now the picture is disturbed along the edges of what used to be the object, there is the ugly shadow.

[image]

Can you advise me how to correct it so it would look like the object was never there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Next time try to expand (and feather) your selection a bit by using the `Refine Selection` function. This might help getting rid of the edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Spot Healing Brush if you want to do it fast. If you want good quality result I would suggest that you take your time and fix it with the Clone Stamp Tool. The Clone Stamp Tool is perfect for this kind of texture. Make sure you sample frequently.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the help of content aware Fill by selecting edges in parts As I had shown in this video CHECK IT
 
http://youtu.be/pHBN3LuwQlc

Video Steps

By Lasso tool select the edges you want to remove

After Selecting edges go to Edit Menu

Edit Menu :: Fill command and select their CONTENT AWARE

Press OK

Your edge will be removed cleanly

Note : Do not select all edges at same time , select edges in parts for better results.

Comment: As someone already commented to one of your answers; Please refrain from advertising your website, if it's not directly related to the question.

Comment: could you please explain what is shown in the video, however short? This leaves your answer valuable even is the video goes down or the link breaks later. Thanks!

Comment: sure I edit my answer and explain my video in this too.

Answer (score 0):

After using the Quick Select tool, go to `Select > Modify > Expand` and expand your selection by a pixel or two. Then use the Content Aware function, and there shouldn't be an edge.